# Generating SAS Token in Salesforce APEX

Tags: javascript, azure, salesforce, blob, apex

I am struggling for a week and now to a point to generate a SAS Token. But still I am unable to pass the Authorization.

Following is the error I am getting

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
    <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:854b47a8-e01e-004e-2746-fc3888000000
Time:2020-03-17T10:26:29.3224986Z</Message>
    <AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature fields not well formed.</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

Following is my simple method using Salesforce APEX. I have hide the Account key

```
public void generateSASToken()
    {
        string storageKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXFbF9ndVdcdl==';
        Datetime sasExpiry = Datetime.now();
        sasExpiry.addMinutes(15);
        sasExpiry = getUTCDateTime(sasExpiry);

        System.debug('sasExpiry-->'+sasExpiry);

        String url='https://zaindevtesting.blob.core.windows.net/zaindevblob/test.txt?sv=2019-02-02&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=w&se=2020-03-18T15:56:39Z&st=2020-03-17T07:56:39Z&spr=https&sig=';
        String stringToSign = 'w\n2020-03-17T07:56:39Z\n2020-03-18T15:56:39Z\n/zaindevtesting/zaindevblob\nYWJjZGVmZw==\n2019-02-02';
        String signature = '';
        Blob unicodeKey = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(storageKey);
        Blob data = Crypto.generateMac('HMACSHA256', Blob.valueOf(stringToSign), unicodeKey);
        signature = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(data);
        url = url + signature;
        System.debug('signature--->'+url);
        System.debug('signature--->'+signature);

    }
```

I am using following Microsoft Doc
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/storageservices/service-sas-examples

Please help me , I dont mind if someone propose alternative solution.

Thanks,
Zain

Comment: You need to follow instructions described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas.

Comment: @ Gaurav Mantri I have followed this Doc also but is not working. I maybe doing some mistake which I am not able to catch. Can you please provide sample code for APEX

Comment: Please share the code that you wrote based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas.

Comment: @ Gaurav Mantri following is my other Post in whihc I have mention multiple way to pass authentication but couldnt do it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60692538/implementing-azure-put-blob-in-salesforce-apex/60692663?noredirect=1#comment107393279_60692663

Comment: This option I havent tried because its more complex and involved AUTH also, I am not able to do simple example cant jump on this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/storageservices/create-user-delegation-sas#construct-a-user-delegation-sas